# I need to change this script of twitter bulk follow to 5 seconds interval per follow?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

.I need 5 seconds interval after each follow, here is my code...

```
__cnt__=0;
jQuery('.Grid-cell .not-following .follow-text').each(function (i, ele) {
    ele = jQuery(ele);
    if (ele.css('display')!='block') {
         console.log('already following:', i); 
         return;
    }
    setTimeout(function () {
        ele.click();
    }, __cnt__++*500);
});
```

Comment: Try to use cnt++*5000

Comment: Thanks..... it worked :-)

Comment: Great, ;) please select my answer as correct

Comment: one more thing i want to ask is as i am using this script below to scroll down the page......but its going down and down and down ..... how can i set this to 50 times trigger to end of the page.?....or any other script is there to stop the down process once i am done with scroling down??                        . setInterval(function() { window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight); }, 2000);

Comment: With $(window).scroll you can determine where is the scroll current position. Just check if it's the same as scroll height and in that case, don't scroll any more

Comment: plz also tell me how to trigger only 1000 times in the above script instead of infinity cnt=0; jQuery('.Grid-cell .not-following .follow-text').each(function (i, ele) { ele = jQuery(ele); if (ele.css('display')!='block') {console.log('already following:', i); return;} setTimeout(function () {ele.click();}, cnt++*500); });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `cnt++*5000` as the time is specified in milliseconds

As far as i know in jQuery you can't specify the number of times you want to execute. Try putting the

```
setTimeout
```

method inside a loop with 1000 iterations with the delay you want to use